# How to append 2 pieces of PHP code, when sending an array of data?

Tags: php, phpmailer, cart

I have sessions variables, in which are stored cart data, and I want to send those via email. This is the loop to write all cart data.

```
foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
            {
          ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $values["item_quantity"]; ?></td>
            <td>€ <?php echo $values["item_price"]; ?></td>
            <td>€ <?php echo number_format($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"], 2);?></td>
            <td><a href="cart.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["item_id"]; ?>"><span class="text-danger">Vymazať</span></a></td>
          </tr>
          <?php
              $total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"]);
            }
```

This is my code to send email and I want to put in there the cart data...

```
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
                    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

                    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
                    $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
                    $mail->Port=995;
                    $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
                    $mail->SMTPSecure='ssl';
                    $mail->Username='deelakeObjednavky@gmail.com';
                    $mail->Password='password';

                    $mail->setFrom($_POST['email'],"Deelake - objednávka");
                    $mail->addAddress('deelakeObjednavky@gmail.com');
                    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'],$_POST['meno']);

                    $mail->isHTML(true);
                    $mail->Subject = 'Vyplnený kontaktný formulár:Objednávka';
                    $mail->Body='<h1 align=center>New ORDER </h1>';

                    if (!$mail->send()) {
                        $result="Email error.";
                    }
                    else{
                        $result="Email success.";
                    }
```

Comment: What is stopping you? You have the loop, you have the script to send the email. You can join them so that the table entries that you are creating in your loop get appended to you `$mail->Body`. Are you getting errors?

Comment: I tried to append it, but it didnt work, i didnt do it right probably

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your attempt, and the specific problem you're running into? Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I dont have a specific attempt right now, but these are the code i need to append, and I dont know how to... I am out of ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following for the `$mail->Body` part:

```
$mail->Body = '<h1 align=center>New ORDER </h1>';
$mail->Body .= '<table>';

$total = 0;

foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values) {
    $mail->Body .= "<tr>
        <td>" . $values["item_name"] . "</td>
        <td>" . $values["item_quantity"] . "</td>
        <td>&euro;" . $values["item_price"] . "</td>
        <td>&euro;" . number_format($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"], 2) . "</td>
        <td><a href=\"cart.php?action=delete&id=" . $values["item_id"] . "><span class=\"text-danger\">Vymazať</span></a></td>
    </tr>";
    $total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"]);
}

$mail->Body .= '</table>';
$mail->Body .= "Total: &euro;" . $total;

if (!$mail->send()) {
    $result = "Email error.";
} else {
    $result = "Email success.";
}
```